# Xcode 12 'carthage update' Bus error 10 - while running for large number of framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage, bus-error

Current carthage version - 0.34
When I have large number of framework ( say 100 + ), 'carthage update' with xcode12 +, getting

**'Bus error: 10'**

Tried restarting system, cleared cache and even after running
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit

Same error. Any way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Try to update carthage version 0.36 or above.

if still not working,

**Step2:**

Yes, I tried a lot myself and found this from official carthage git page.
Try the below command and it worked for me!!

[image]

**Note:** Use carthage version 0.36 and above